The system cannot find the file specified. (WSL) I cant use any wsl command in cmd/powershell even in admin mode
I ran into this problem where i cant use any wsl command in my cmd/powershell during updating docker even when i run them as admin.
I used the turn off then on feature WSL and VMP. Still not working.
I tried to disable, enable using dism.exe. The operation work normally and it even return the message:
"Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 10.0.22621.2792
Image Version: 10.0.22631.4037
Feature Information:
Feature Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux Display Name : Windows Subsystem for Linux Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows. Restart Required : Possible State : Enabled
Custom Properties:
ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows. ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux ServerComponent\Id : 1033 ServerComponent\Type : Feature ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
The operation completed successfully."
I reset the system multiple times, even waited 8s before restart. The problem remain the same. I did research for answers and come through like 5 or 6 methods and none of them work. ChatGPT, stackoverflow, superuser, microsoft,... i tried. The only think i can think of is i accidently deleted a file/system file and screw thing up. But according to chatGPT turn off then on the feature WSL will reinstall the core files needed. I downloaded the wsl_update_x64.msi, ran it, the problem still there. In apps and feature, i see the WSL app, but cant enter its advanced settings, theres only 1 option is to uninstall it. I stuck with this problem for like 3 hours now, and i really need WSL for docker and ubuntu.

i did add wsl to the environment variables.
